# Golang math slow execution when using code

Tags: go

Problem: using code from the math package is much slower than using the math package.

The code below is copied from the math module but `math.Sqrt` performs much faster than `sqrt`. My question is: Why, and what can be done?

Example: (Note, the function of interest is not math.Sqrt. I want to write a custom version of a combination of functions.)

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "unsafe"
)

const (
    uvnan    = 0x7FF8000000000001
    uvinf    = 0x7FF0000000000000
    uvneginf = 0xFFF0000000000000
    uvone    = 0x3FF0000000000000
    mask     = 0x7FF
    shift    = 64 - 11 - 1
    bias     = 1023
    signMask = 1 << 63
    fracMask = 1<<shift - 1
)

func Float64bits(f float64) uint64 { return *(*uint64)(unsafe.Pointer(&f)) }
func Float64frombits(b uint64) float64 { return *(*float64)(unsafe.Pointer(&b)) }
func sqrt(x float64) float64 {
    // special cases
    ix := Float64bits(x)
    // normalize x
    exp := int((ix >> shift) & mask)
    if exp == 0 { // subnormal x
        for ix&(1<<shift) == 0 {
            ix <<= 1
            exp--
        }
        exp++
    }
    exp -= bias // unbias exponent
    ix &^= mask << shift
    ix |= 1 << shift
    if exp&1 == 1 { // odd exp, double x to make it even
        ix <<= 1
    }
    exp >>= 1 // exp = exp/2, exponent of square root
    // generate sqrt(x) bit by bit
    ix <<= 1
    var q, s uint64               // q = sqrt(x)
    r := uint64(1 << (shift + 1)) // r = moving bit from MSB to LSB
    for r != 0 {
        t := s + r
        if t <= ix {
            s = t + r
            ix -= t
            q += r
        }
        ix <<= 1
        r >>= 1
    }
    // final rounding
    if ix != 0 { // remainder, result not exact
        q += q & 1 // round according to extra bit
    }
    ix = q>>1 + uint64(exp-1+bias)<<shift // significand + biased exponent
    return Float64frombits(ix)
}

func main() {
    n_iter := 100000000
    var x float64
    var y float64
    for i := 0; i < n_iter; i++ {
        y = math.Sqrt(2426.1)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Done\n") // Much, much faster

    for i := 0; i < n_iter; i++ {
        x = sqrt(2426.1)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Done\n")
    fmt.Printf("%f/%f\n", x, y)
}
```

Comment: Probably math.Sqrt for your architecture isn't done in software but native in hardware. So much for the why. I'm not sure I understand the second part of the question: Use math.Sqrt?

Comment: The comment for that function says: _"Note: On systems where Sqrt is a single instruction, the compiler may turn a direct call into a direct use of that instruction instead."_

Comment: Thank you JimB, I will accept this as an answer if you post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the generated code for `math.Sqrt`. Build this `main.go` with `-S` flag:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "math/rand"
)

func main() {
    x := rand.Float64()
    y := math.Sqrt(x)
    fmt.Println(y)
}
```

Generate assembly: `go build -gcflags='-S' main.go`

```
...
        0x000e 00014 (./main.go:10)     PCDATA  $1, $0
        0x000e 00014 (./main.go:10)     CALL    math/rand.Float64(SB)
        0x0013 00019 (/home/user/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/toolchain@v0.0.1-go1.21.5.linux-amd64/src/math/sqrt.go:94)    SQRTSD  X0, X0
        0x0017 00023 (./main.go:12)     MOVQ    X0, AX
        0x001c 00028 (./main.go:11)     XCHGL   AX, AX
...
```

As you can see, the actual call is `SQRTSD` machine instruction.

It is governed by [`cmd/compile/internal/ssagen/ssa.go`](https://go.googlesource.com/go/+/refs/heads/master/src/cmd/compile/internal/ssagen/ssa.go#4583) configuration: on platforms `sys.I386, sys.AMD64, sys.ARM, sys.ARM64, sys.Loong64, sys.MIPS, sys.MIPS64, sys.PPC64, sys.RISCV64, sys.S390X, sys.Wasm` the compiler inserts `SQRT` opcode.

You can also check many other functions replaced with assembly.

BTW. In the example I call `math.Sqrt` on a random argument, because for literal values the compiler computes the square root itself and compiles in the actual value.

Here is the assembly code for `math.Sqrt(2.0)`

```
0x0014 00020 (./main.go:11)     MOVQ    $4609047870845172685, AX
0x001e 00030 (./main.go:11)     PCDATA  $1, $1
0x001e 00030 (./main.go:11)     NOP
0x0020 00032 (./main.go:11)     CALL    runtime.convT64(SB)
0x0025 00037 (./main.go:11)     LEAQ    type:float64(SB), CX
```

The value `4609047870845172685` is the actual `sqrt(2)` in 64 bit representation.

Comment: Very helpful and clear! Also good to know that values are precomputed. In my case, that means that I am comparing a MOV with a long sequence of operations. In other words: must change the test to include rand.