# Abnormally low execution time using time.Since() for calculating square roots?

Tags: go, math, time, math.sqrt

I'm new to go and I was learning Go using the Go Tour. One of the challenges was to find a square root of a number. A formula was given with an initial value of 1.

After fiddling with it for a long while, I did some math to find a somewhat better initial value (~25-35% less average iterations, ~7-10% less average error). This initial seems better with bigger numbers.

Next thing I wanted to do was to check how long it takes for my function to compute square root of 1 to 100,000. Just for fun.

Looking at Go's time package, I made use of the `time.Now()` and `time.Since()` functions to calculate both my function's total time and `math.Sqrt()` total time. But the numbers are oddly very, very low (~3ms for my function, 0 `math.Sqrt()`).

I'm not sure if my timing code is incorrect, if my function actually only takes ~3ms (excluding printouts), and why `math.Sqrt()` takes 0 time? (Is it perhaps already computed and it is just looking it up?), perhaps somne kind of threading action is happening?

I have no idea.

Here is all my code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

func Sqrt(x float64) (float64, float64) {
    count := 0
    initial := 1
    // initial = 1<<2^(digit count)
    for n := x;n > 1; {
        n = n / 10
        initial = initial<<2
        count++
    }

    z := x / float64(initial)
    var p float64
    i := 0.0
    for ; math.Abs(z-p) > 0.0000000001; i = i + 1 {
        p = z
        z -= (z*z - x) / (2 * z)
    }

    return z, i
}

func compute(x int) (float64, float64) {

    input := float64(x)
    guess, iterations := Sqrt(input)
    expected := math.Sqrt(input)
    err := float64(math.Abs(guess-expected))
    fmt.Printf("Sqrt: %v\nExpected: %v\nGuess: %v\nError: %v\nIterations: %v\n\n", input, expected, guess, err, iterations)
    return iterations, err
}

func main() {
    size := 100000
    var totalIterations []int
    var totalErrs []string
    var iterSum float64
    var errSum float64

    
    for i := 1; i < size + 1; i++ {
        iter, err := compute(i)
        totalIterations = append(totalIterations, int(iter))
        formatedErr := strconv.FormatFloat(err, 'E', -1, 64)
        totalErrs = append(totalErrs, formatedErr)
        iterSum += iter
        errSum += err
    }

    fmt.Printf("Iterations sum %v\nAverage iteration count: %v\nError sum: %v\nError average: %v\n", iterSum, iterSum/float64(len(totalIterations)), errSum, errSum/float64(len(totalErrs)))

    // re-running the loops for finding time (temporary), I will incoperate it to the above loop later
    customTimeStart := time.Now()
    for i := 1; i < size + 1; i++ {
        Sqrt(float64(i))
    }
    elapsedCustom := time.Since(customTimeStart)

    mathTimeStart := time.Now()
    for i := 1; i < size + 1; i++ {
        math.Sqrt(float64(i))
    }
    elapsedMath := time.Since(mathTimeStart)
    
    fmt.Printf("Total custom time: %s\nTotal math time: %s\n", elapsedCustom, elapsedMath)
}
```

Comment: 3 milliseconds is practically _forever_ for basic math operations, even a million of them. What makes you think it's too short? A more important question is: does the code actually run? Because if the code ran, and you got the results you expected, then... =)

Comment: Also, remember that CPUs are _really, really good_ at arithmetic. Square root may not be as fast as adding or subtracting, running in the tens of clock cycles, but at <100 cycles on a 3GHz CPU, that's still "at most a single digit nanosecond" territory. Your code runs 100,000 iterations, which moves us over to "at most double digit microsecond territory". If you comment off all your print statements except the last and run your program over and over, you'll sometimes see it report a non-zero value: this is just how fast CPUs are. They're _really_ fast =)

Comment: I suppose you are right. Still, math.Sqrt didnt even take 1 microsecond (doesnt time.Since have precision of nanosecond actually?). I just didn't know if I was timing it correctly that's all. Otherwise I am very happy with the code I produced :)

Comment: Go can do nanoseconds, but if you want to _actually_ benchmark, you probably want to [use `testing.Benchmark`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8350913/740553) rather than writing your own timestamp comparisons, which reports that your custom square root takes (on my machine at least) 31.6 ns/op, whereas math.Sqrt takes 0.2172 ns/op.

Comment: Oh damn lol. didn't think the difference would be that huge. Thanks for pointing out how all this information!

Comment: Note that `0.2172 ns/op` is mostly meaningless. The builtin `math.Sqrt` is being compiled to a single CPU instruction, but `0.2172ns` is really indistinguishable from being optimized away completely.

Comment: `time` functions should not be considered reliable time-keeping for such short durations. `time.Time` values encode time with fixed precision, and "nanosecond precision" just means that they choose 1ns as the internal time units. It has no bearing on the usable precision of actual clock measurements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Golang compiler optimizes `math.Sqrt` function by replacing it with a call to the internal function `math.sqrt`. Subsequently, on most hardware platforms, including the AMD64 architecture, the compiler further substitutes `math.sqrt` with platform-dependent `SQRT` opcode. For AMD64, it is `SQRTSD` assembly instruction (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77887525/golang-math-slow-execution-when-using-code/77895632#77895632) ).

As a result, calls to math.Sqrt exhibit extremely fast execution times, measured in fractions of nanoseconds. You can verify these optimizations by compiling your program into assembly using the command `go build -gcflags=-S some.go`.

Then check the assembly for `compute` function:

```
        0x001a 00026 (/mnt/d/tmp/try-go/trygo/some.go:33)       XORPS   X0, X0
        0x001d 00029 (/mnt/d/tmp/try-go/trygo/some.go:33)       CVTSQ2SD        AX, X0
        0x0022 00034 (/mnt/d/tmp/try-go/trygo/some.go:33)       MOVSD   X0, main.input+72(SP)
        0x0028 00040 (/mnt/d/tmp/try-go/trygo/some.go:34)       PCDATA  $1, $0
        0x0028 00040 (/mnt/d/tmp/try-go/trygo/some.go:34)       CALL    main.Sqrt(SB)
        0x002d 00045 (/mnt/d/tmp/try-go/trygo/some.go:34)       MOVSD   X1, main.iterations+64(SP)
        0x0033 00051 (/usr/local/go/src/math/sqrt.go:94)        MOVSD   main.input+72(SP), X2
        0x0039 00057 (/usr/local/go/src/math/sqrt.go:94)        SQRTSD  X2, X3
        0x003d 00061 (/mnt/d/tmp/try-go/trygo/some.go:36)       MOVUPS  X0, X4
        0x0040 00064 (/mnt/d/tmp/try-go/trygo/some.go:36)       SUBSD   X3, X0
```

See this line `0x0039 00057 (/usr/local/go/src/math/sqrt.go:94)        SQRTSD  X2, X3`? This is what Go compiler generated for `math.Sqrt` call.

**Benchmarking**

Go has a better way to evaluate performance. It is called benchmarking

```
package main

import (
    "math"
    "math/rand"
    "testing"
)

func BenchmarkMathSqrt(b *testing.B) {
    x := rand.Float64()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        math.Sqrt(x)
    }
}

func BenchmarkCustomSqrt(b *testing.B) {
    x := rand.Float64()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        Sqrt(x)
    }
}
```

Run it: `go test -benchmem -bench ^Benchmark.*$ .`

Result:

```
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
pkg: sqrt
cpu: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz
BenchmarkMathSqrt-8             1000000000               0.2609 ns/op          0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkCustomSqrt-8           60635712                19.72 ns/op            0 B/op          0 allocs/op
PASS
```